# String to int and again to string C++

Tags: c++, string, for-loop, int, getline

i want to program take a string from user and convert it to some numbers(characters), and when numbers increased by 1 unit then put them in an other string and show it.

```
    string text, code;

    cout << "Enter Text: ";
    getline(cin, text);

    for (int i = 0; i < 8 ; i++)
        code[i] = text[i] + '1';
    cout<<code<<endl;
```

for example if i entered as blow:
abcd123
result be as blow:
bcde234

but when i run this, after my input it gets an error :(

Comment: Doesn't have to do anything with your title.

Comment: You need to change `'1'` to `1`. It should be a integer value to increment the character value, and not a `char` value.

Comment: dear user007, i tried what you told, but it dident work after too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the error is that the string `code` is unitialised, and accessing it at index `i` is UB. To fix this, add the following line after reading the input and putting it in the string `text`

```
code = text; // Giving it the exact value of text is redundant. The main point is to initialise it to appropriate size.
```

Besides that, instead of

```
code[i] = text[i] + '1';
```

It should be

```
code[i] = text[i] + 1;
```

You could also modify the code as follows to avoid the `code` variable and make it more concise:

```
text[i]++;
```

Comment: @danirzv : Explain properly what you tried. What were the specific error messages. We can't help you unless you do that.

Comment: "code = text;" and "code[i] = text[i] + 1;" helped me, thank you so much.

Comment: @DanialRazavi: The more important thing is that you understood what you were doing wrong, and learnt something from the answer.

Comment: i'm 100% agree with you, and thank you for what you taught me :)